# How to notify progress from inside service classes in domain model

Tags: c#, events, notifications, progress

My WPF solution has a GUI with views and viewmodels, and a class library with domain objects.
One of the main steps in the application workflow involves a relative long operation with many different numeric computations.

So, I have a `ComputationManager` class with an `Execute()` method. This execute method instantiates, say, `FirstComputation`, `SecondComputation` and `ThirdComputation` classes, and calls their `Execute()` methods in sequence. Some of these classes instantiate yet other `AnotherSubComputation` classes, with a hierarchical structure simplified below.

```
class ComputationManager {

    public void Execute() {

        var first = new FirstComputation();
        first.Execute();
        var firstresult = first.result;

        var second = new SecondComputation();
        second.Execute();
        ....
    }
}
```

Since the operation as a whole takes some time to achieve, the ViewModel where the computation occurs is using a `BackgroundWorker`, and `ComputationManager` is instantiated inside the `DoWork` handler.

But this is not enough, since I have to receive progress from the `Computation` classes somehow, so here is my question:

> How are classes in a class library supposed to notify client code about progress of their executing activities?

I believe that listening to events is the way to go, but I'm not sure, specially because I have never developed multithreaded code, and most probably the vast .NET framework has some pre-packed way to do this.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason to use events here, other than the PropertyChange event.

I would just put a property in the ComputationManager class called Progress (of type int - values from 0 to 100). This property will raise the PropertyChange event on the setter. Obviously your ComputationManager will need to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

The your user interface (probably a progress indication control, or even a simple label) will bind to this property and display the progress.

I don't know how granular and detailed your progress indication should be. For instance you could just change the progress indication when each one of your sub computation completes. Anyway they are executed sequentially.

Comment: Your tip is nice, but the activities that actually take some time to run are in the second or third level below the hierarchy, and `NthComputation` classes are all private. What I want is a way for `ComputationManager` to know about its subtasks inner progress. We could say that the inner classes will "bubble up" their progress up tu the `ComputationManager` class, which then will raise the `BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged` event.